# Send input to running program Batch

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

I would like to start a cmd line program in Batch and be able to communicate with it.

Currently I am starting the program with `start /b cmd /c  "cli_program.exe" > log.txt`. I am currently redirecting the output to a log file so that I can <s>`grep`</s> `findstr` the output.

Is there another way that I can get/send info to and from `cli_program.exe`? For example, is there a way to watch the output and if everything works, send an `ENTER` to proceed. or dynamically answer prompts coming from `cli_program.exe` (not predefine them in a text file and passing that at start?)?

Comment: Try autoit or autohotkey instead. Or python.

Comment: @Gantendo I'm really trying to maximize compatibility. The user will most likely not have many developer tools or libraries installed

Comment: You can turn a script into a .exe which contains everything it needs (which would maximize compatibility).